# Подключить функцию из файла function.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Как я могу подключить функцию в WordPress, из файла function.php, таким образом, чтобы она работала только для одной страницы?

```
if( is_page( '285' ) ):

    function searchfilter($query) {

        if( $query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
            $query->set('post_type', array('projects'));
        }

        return $query;
    }

    add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
endif;
```

У меня есть такой код, но он не работает. Kто подскажет, в чём проблема?

Comment: is_page() Подробнее на kama

Comment: if ( is_page( '285' ) ) :

function searchfilter($query) {

  if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ){
        $query->set('post_type',array('projects'));
    }

return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');

endif;

Comment: @KAGGDesign Почему не работает этот скрипт?

Comment: Это другой вопрос

Comment: @KAGGDesign без is_page, скрипт работает Ho на всех страницах, не знаешь в чём проблема?

Comment: В том, что не там написано. Отредактируй вопрос, добавит туда код

Answer (score 0):

Условные теги не работают прямо в `functions.php`. На момент подключения этого файла в ядре ещё не установлен главный запрос WordPress, поэтому `is_page()` с любыми аргументами и без них возвращает false.

Условный тег должен быть использован внутри хука:

```
function searchfilter( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search && ! is_admin() ) {
        if ( is_page( '285' ) ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'projects' ) );
        }
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'searchfilter' );
```

Но и такой код неправильный. `is_search()` и `is_page()` никогда не вернут `true` одновременно. Из вопроса непонятно, что именно вы хотите сделать.